# How do I exclude multi-line set of data when ONE line of data has a specific value? SQL-ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

I hope I didn't miss an answer already posted that would help me. Forgive me if I did.
 Let's assume to get the below query results, I have inner joined the Item table to the Pricing table on the Item value.
My current query returns something similar to this:

```
Item______Price
Item1_____Price1  
Item1_____Price2  
Item1_____Price3  
Item2_____Price2  
Item2_____Price3  
Item3_____Price1  
Item3_____Price2  
Item3_____Price3
```

I want to only return the SET (both lines) for Item 2 since Price1 does not exist for that Item. Since Item1 and Item3 contain rows that have Price1 on them, I want to exclude ALL rows for those items.
I want to pull back

```
Item______Price  
Item2_____Price2  
Item2_____Price3
```

I have tried the following on my script and it didn't return ANY results. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong and I am still very green when it comes to writing and understanding this stuff.

AND NOT EXISTS (
                      SELECT *
                      FROM sqlmgr.PRICE P2
                      AND (P2.PRICE = 'PRICE1')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a correlated subquery for the `NOT EXISTS`:

```
NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
            FROM sqlmgr.PRICE P2
            WHERE p2.ITEM = p.ITEM AND P2.PRICE = 'PRICE1'
           )
```

Your version returns nothing because there are records that have `PRICE1` in them -- without the correlation piece (`p2.ITEM = p.ITEM`), it would check the entire table instead of just the item of interest on a given row.

Note that `p` is the alias of the table in the outer query, whatever that might be.